# org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-mvc, post

I want to send form data to my controller usign AJAX. Below what i have tried so for..

**My Javascript function**

```
<script>
      function masterRegistration(){


          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./masterRegistrationData",

            success: function(data){
                console.log("SUCCESS ", data);
            },
            error: function(e){
                console.log("ERROR ", e);
            }

        });
      }
</script>
```

**My controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/masterRegistrationData", method = RequestMethod.POST )
   public String register(HttpServletRequest request) throws ParseException {

}
```

I do not know where i am wrong. i am getting below error in controller

**org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported**

Please make me correct..

Answer (score 0):

Try this and in browser developer tool check network tab and see what url is generated while making ajax call

```
<script>
  function masterRegistration(){
      var ctx = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}";

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ctx +"/masterRegistrationData",

        success: function(data){
            console.log("SUCCESS ", data);
        },
        error: function(e){
            console.log("ERROR ", e);
        }

    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried as you said it will hit wrong URL. I need to put "."  before masterRegistrationData.

Comment: Ok do one thing pass full path in above url and then see if it works . check network in browser developer tool I am sure you will get your answer in network tool.

Comment: And also can you post your request mapping code from class file